# Funds and Wallets

Tags: wallet, security, address

If I load bitcoins to my wallet and the funds are there, and I go back to load more Bitcoins with a new address for my wallet are the funds from my first wallet going to merge with the newly added funds from the new generated wallet ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an incorrect view of the way wallets work.  A wallet is a collection of addresses, so whenever you receive any transfers by any address in your wallet it is added to your 'collection' of transactions.  So yes, if you use two different addresses pointing to the same wallet the sum total of the two transactions will be added to your wallet.